# How do I display an integer with a function that only accepts a char in C?

Tags: c, char, int

I'm going to do my best to explain exactly what my problem is. I'm currently taking an embedded systems class and I'm really struggling with this portion of the project. I have a small STM32 board with a simple LCD screen connected to it. I have a function already written that will take a single char and write it to the LCD. Now, I often use that function to write char's but there is one scenario in which I need to write an int between 0 and 99 to the screen. The int variable is always changing because it is based on the value in a timer when a user presses the button on the board. I have been stumped by this for hours and I could really use some help. I have emailed my teacher but he isn't replying. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, the LCD_write function is already provided to me by my teacher so I can't just create a version of it that will accept an int.

If I haven't given enough detail just let me know.

Comment: You mean you have a function to print a char and now you have problems calling it twice in a row based on grade school mathematics? What did you try?

Comment: Thank you for the snide and unhelpful response. The guy below actually helped. I was having a hard time figuring out on my own what he stated below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert your int to two chars:

```
char ch0 = i % 10 + '0'; // convert least significant digit to char
char ch1 = i / 10 + '0'; // convert most significant digit to char
```

Note: this assumes that you can guarantee that the int is always in the range 0..99.

Comment: Obviously this needs to be improved to support values < 0  or > 99, but the general idea is clear.

Comment: @littleadv: the OP stated that the int is in the range 0..99.

Comment: No worries - I've added a comment about the range of the int to the answer now.

Comment: Thanks man, that did the trick for me. I should have been able to figure that out myself but things start to get hard to figure out after staring at code for hours, haha.

Comment: I also realized after I wrote this that my actual int range is -1000 to 1000 but I was able to adapt this to work.